# Angular 8 auth guard, proxy token exposes front-end pages?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, bearer-token

I'm learning angular 8, and once I completed the auth guard topic. I tested the autherization in angular with tokens. But if I proxy the token in console and route to a protected component, it moves to that component and exposes the component. How can we solve such problems?? The backend is secure since it is verifying the token, so no problem in backend. Do anyone kow the solution? Please help me in this situation??

Comment: What do you mean by proxy the token in the console? Can you explain the problem in more detailed question?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHashem just set a name as token in local storage from console...**localStorage.setItem('token','name')**, and inserted the protected route in url it exposes the protected component...

Comment: I understood, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the signature is validated on the server when the JWT is sent back with each request (in a cookie or in the Authorization header).

However, if you need to validate the JWT on the client-side to use its claims, for example, you should use a private/public key pair to sign and validate, respectively, the JWT.

So you have the public key in your client-side to validate the JWT's signature in your guard every time you try to access that page or component.

If it is valid, then you are good. Proceed to that page.

Otherwise, the JWT token had been played with.

Comment: well,  how can we protect a component when using auth guard, since auth guard only check whether there token is present or not, if present then authenticate that component and I didn't get your solution mentioned...

Comment: First, you need to sign this token by your server with its private key.
After that, you get the server public key in your client-side (Angular App). Validate the already signed JWT.
The validation process using the public key will return either true or false.
If false, then the token is messed up and you should not allow the user to access. Otherwise, the token is valid and you give the user access to that page or component.